# Issues with dependencies between multiple instances of PostgreSQL and PostGIS on the same computer

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I have multiple instances of PostgreSQL installed on my Mac, namely:

- /Library/PostgreSQL/14/ (never used, don't know the version)
- /Library/PostgreSQL/15/ (PostgreSQL 15.2)
- /opt/homebrew/Cellar/postgresql@14/ (PostgreSQL 14.10 (Homebrew))

Each version of PostgreSQL has its own installation of PostGIS.

I have set up a new database on server PostgreSQL 14.10 (Homebrew) and I'm trying to add the PostGIS extension with the following command:

```
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS postgis;
```

However, I get the following error message:

```
ERROR:  could not open extension control file
"/Library/PostgreSQL/14/share/postgresql/extension/postgis.control":
No such file or directory
```

I understand that the problem is that PostgreSQL 14.10 (Homebrew) is trying to create the extension by using the version of PostGIS that's installed in the PostgreSQL 15.2 server, and that it should be trying to use the one installed on Homebrew in the PostgreSQL 14.10 (Homebrew) server. But I don't know how to fix it. I believe it's an issue of dependencies.

How do I get the PostgreSQL 14.10 (Homebrew) server to "speak" to the PostGIS that was installed with Homebrew?

Comment: Use docker it’s fixes such problems…

Comment: Are you sure that the new database you created was on the Homebrew instance of Postgres 14 not the one located at `/Library/PostgreSQL/14/`? Have you verified what Postgres instances are up and running?